# CSS: border is taller than div container

Tags: html, css

I was making a menu for my website, where i had overflow hidden, so borders height wouldn't be bigger than menu, But after some time i needed to get rid of `overflow:hidden` option.

After i got rid of the parameter, twice as tall borders appeared at the bottom.

This is the related style i use for buttons on my navigator menu:

```
.Button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  right: 15%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 7%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 0%;
  padding: 25px 2px 55px 2px;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

I have tried `no-repeat` option with no success, the borders would completely disappear afterwards.

After that, i have tried setting `padding-bottom` value to `0`, which didn't make a change.

`box-sizing` is set to `border-box`:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I also tried setting height value to `0`, which also did not make any change.

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bmqupdwf/embedded/result/) ( profile picture is sample, so it is not the problem ).

---

So what can the problem be? How can i get rid of it without hiding the overflow of menu? Is there some anchor tag that i have made incorrectly?

Comment: the anchor tag height is bigger than the menu height

Comment: I can't find anything relevant, could you show me where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `box-sizing: border-box`, it doesn't allow the padding to increase the dimensions of your element

Comment: In the code i have `*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: remove max-height from menu will solve the issue, and for better css practice give all your buttons one class

Comment: Thanks it almost solved my problem, but now buttons are very large, how can i minimize them?

Comment: I am sorry for bothering too much, but exactly which padding? i have tried padding-top which would make text top of course, but when i tried lessening bottom padding it didn't have any effect.

Comment: in here: padding: 25px 2px 55px 2px; change the 3rd value

Comment: Yes, i've tried the third value, (padding-bottom) but it didn't have any effect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cn66zega/                    by changing line-height and height in menu, you can change the button size

Comment: Thanks! worked! now i still have final issue, now the `profilebar` elements seem not to stay in container :(.

Comment: remove line-height and add padding-top:2em, to the menu

Comment: This would bring down all the element text and remove half of the borders of it: https://jsfiddle.net/cn66zega/2/embedded/result/

Comment: sorry, put it only on the button then, and give separate padding on the dropdown, also give 100% height to the profile bar, things should be nice and smooth now

Comment: I am so sorry, i am kind of newbie to css, i tried giving 100% height to profile bar, can you show me the final fiddle? Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

OK Buddy !

Try to check the padding you have but in the button & you can try changing height by this :

"height:10px !important;"

Comment: This wouldn't fix the problem, i think this is not the height, i have tried setting it to 0% without noticing any change, maybe it's padding.

Comment: @ShellRox You need to check the padding option first. It will surely solve your problem. But if then you want to increase the height you can use that height command. " !important " overwrites any other style effect given before that command.

Comment: I don't understand sorry, i have tried minimizing padding bottom but the border was still overflowing menu.

Comment: is there a way you can send me an image for the same to my mail id or attach a photo on here regarding it? mail id is : jainishkothary135@gmail.com